# Portable Class library object serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, xamarin

I am working on Xamarin iOS application. I also want to develop the same application for Android as well.  So I am planning to write most of the code in a portable class library project.

The issue that I am facing now is, I cannot serialize the object of the class that created inside the “Portable class library” project. The **“[Serializable]”** attribute not supported inside the portable class library. I want to implement binary format serialization inside the portable class library project . How I achieve this.

Any help would ne appreciable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would strongly suggest *not* using the built-in binary serialization even if you could... and it sounds like basically can't anyway. There are plenty of alternatives for serialization, depending on your requirements. You could consider:

- JSON (e.g. with Json.NET)
- Protocol Buffers
- YAML
- XML

These have different trade-off in terms of whether you need to make the data that you're serializing separate to your normal code or whether they can serialize "in-place", the readability, efficiency etc. But all are nice and portable, not just between .NET/Xamarin implementations but also other platforms.

Comment: Thanks!! If we use Json,Xml etc serialization and save the object as a file , then user can  read the content when he opened the file. Right? How can we prevent the readability of the file like binary format serialization?

Comment: @Ranish: Binary format serialization doesn't prevent the file from being read - it just makes it harder. If that's what you care about, Protocol Buffers use a binary format too, which is at least tricky to read by hand - but it's not genuine content protection. (Just be aware that this is unlikely to make a long-lasting difference...)

Comment: How to handle existing objects? I used to write my own serializer in the past and used the `SerializableAttribute` for existing classes from .NET, as the attribute is not available in the PCL profiles there must be other ways to do the serialization. I've some ideas, what is your approach?

Comment: @FelixK.: I would probably write a desktop app to convert existing binary-serialized data to whatever alternative format you use.

Comment: I think you missunderstood me, i meant existing objects like a `List<T>` has originaly a `_syncRoot` which has the attribute `NonSerialized` attribute. However this attribute is not available in PCL. Manual filtering would be horrible. Also the `WeakReference` uses a custom contructor. Of course doing it manual for each of those types is possible but seems to me like a lot of work.

Comment: @FelixK.: Sorry, I really don't understand what you're asking about. I suggest you ask a new question, providing a lot more context. I would urge you *not* to use .NET binary serialization.